# Отсутствие перевода в настройках смены темы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тёмная-тема

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/10057
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15527
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15528
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/6247 (уже было кем-то переведено)

Ожидается на свежих сборках. Текущая rev 2020.11.2.37934